# How to get to use GsonSerializer for ktor?

Tags: gson, kotlin-multiplatform, ktor, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

In https://ktor.io/docs/json.html#gson, I can see we can have GsonSerialzer as the code

```
install(JsonFeature) {
    serializer = GsonSerializer() {
        setPrettyPrinting()
        disableHtmlEscaping()
    }
}
```

But I can't seem to get to include this class. Which library should I import (in my Gradle) to have access to them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-gson:$ktor_version"
```

From the [docs](https://ktor.io/docs/json.html#jvm_dependency)

Comment: edit: hold up, I don't see that class in ktor-gson:1.6.0 ( fixed )

Answer (score 3):

A quick note, `GSON` will only work for `JVM` targets as its a java serialization/deserialization library.

If you have native targets then you probably want to use kotlinx-serialization (`ktor-client-serialization`)